# Springboot REST endpoints with Alfresco Process Services (Activiti)

Tags: spring-boot, activiti, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I have installed Alfresco Process Services on my local machine. I have also created a springboot project to write custom listeners like Task listener or execution listeners. These listeners are working fine. **I create a jar file and put it into webapp\activiti-app\WEB-INF\lib folder.**

Now I want to add REST endpoints in my application so that external users can directly take an action on task.

I added the following class beside my main application class which has the main method.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api2")
public class WorkflowController {

@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public String greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
    return  "Hello from " +name;
 }
}
```

The issue is when I try to access the endpoint via any of the below URL it gives me 404 error.

```
http://localhost:8081/activiti-app/api2/greeting 
OR
http://localhost:8081/api2/greeting
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the URL publicly you need to start your mapping with `/enterprise`. APS requires this to distinguish between public and private rest APIs, so your `@RequestMapping("/api2")` should be `@RequestMapping("/enterprise/api2")` which should then be accessible with `http://localhost:8081/activiti-app/api/enterprise/api2/greeting`. refer the [developer series](https://community.alfresco.com/community/bpm/blog/2016/11/18/activiti-enterprise-developer-series-custom-rest-endpoints) for a detailed example.

Comment: Is there any way I can complete the task without login? I mean by clicking on the button in the email ?

Comment: no but you can redirect user to his task, after login he will be able to complete it